# Cannot connect the server when using ant build to deploy web application to local Weblogic server

Tags: deployment, ant, build, weblogic

I am using Weblogic 12. Build was OK. But when deploying the application to local Weblogic, it complained failing to connect the server. The exception is the same as when Weblogic is not running.

Great thanks!

```
    deployWars:
     [wldeploy] weblogic.Deployer -upload -noexit -name GB_MBR -source C:\GB_MBR\dist\GB_MBR.war -targets myserver -adminurl t3://localhost:7001 -user system -password ******** -deploy 
     [wldeploy] weblogic.Deployer invoked with options:  -upload -noexit -name GB_MBR -source C:\GB_MBR\dist\GB_MBR.war -targets myserver -adminurl t3://localhost:7001 -user system -deploy
     [wldeploy] javax.enterprise.deploy.spi.exceptions.DeploymentManagerCreationException: [J2EE Deployment SPI:260010]Unable to connect to "t3://localhost:7001" as user, "system". Error received: null
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.WebLogicDeploymentManagerImpl.<init>(WebLogicDeploymentManagerImpl.java:137)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.deploy.api.spi.factories.internal.DeploymentFactoryImpl.getDeploymentManager(DeploymentFactoryImpl.java:86)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.SessionHelper.getRemoteDeploymentManager(SessionHelper.java:496)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.Jsr88Operation.connect(Jsr88Operation.java:297)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.Deployer.perform(Deployer.java:137)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.Deployer.runBody(Deployer.java:88)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:158)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:115)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.Deployer.run(Deployer.java:74)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.Deployer.mainWithExceptions(Deployer.java:63)
     [wldeploy]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     [wldeploy]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     [wldeploy]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     [wldeploy]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.ant.taskdefs.management.WLDeploy.invokeMain(WLDeploy.java:419)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.ant.taskdefs.management.WLDeploy.execute(WLDeploy.java:349)
     [wldeploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
     [wldeploy]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
     [wldeploy]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     [wldeploy]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     [wldeploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     [wldeploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     [wldeploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
     [wldeploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
     [wldeploy]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
     [wldeploy]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     [wldeploy]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     [wldeploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     [wldeploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     [wldeploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:398)
     [wldeploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
     [wldeploy]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
     [wldeploy]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     [wldeploy]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     [wldeploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     [wldeploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     [wldeploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
     [wldeploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
     [wldeploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
     [wldeploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
     [wldeploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
     [wldeploy]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
     [wldeploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
     [wldeploy]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:424)
     [wldeploy]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:138)
     [wldeploy] Caused by: weblogic.deploy.api.spi.exceptions.ServerConnectionException: [J2EE Deployment SPI:260010]Unable to connect to "t3://localhost:7001" as user, "system". Error received: null
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.internal.ServerConnectionImpl.getMBeanServer(ServerConnectionImpl.java:249)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.internal.ServerConnectionImpl.getMBeanServerForType(ServerConnectionImpl.java:189)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.internal.ServerConnectionImpl.init(ServerConnectionImpl.java:145)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.WebLogicDeploymentManagerImpl.getNewConnection(WebLogicDeploymentManagerImpl.java:164)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.WebLogicDeploymentManagerImpl.<init>(WebLogicDeploymentManagerImpl.java:134)
     [wldeploy]     ... 44 more
     [wldeploy] Caused by: java.io.IOException
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.management.remote.common.ClientProviderBase.makeConnection(ClientProviderBase.java:196)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.management.remote.common.ClientProviderBase.newJMXConnector(ClientProviderBase.java:84)
     [wldeploy]     at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.newJMXConnector(Unknown Source)
     [wldeploy]     at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(Unknown Source)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.internal.ServerConnectionImpl.getMBeanServer(ServerConnectionImpl.java:238)
     [wldeploy]     ... 48 more
     [wldeploy] Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is: 
     [wldeploy]     java.io.EOFException]
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.jrmp.Context.lookup(Context.java:189)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.jrmp.Context.lookup(Context.java:195)
     [wldeploy]     at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.management.remote.common.ClientProviderBase.makeConnection(ClientProviderBase.java:179)
     [wldeploy]     ... 52 more
     [wldeploy] Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is: 
     [wldeploy]     java.io.EOFException
     [wldeploy]     at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(Unknown Source)
     [wldeploy]     at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(Unknown Source)
     [wldeploy]     at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(Unknown Source)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.jrmp.BaseRemoteRef.invoke(BaseRemoteRef.java:221)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.jrmp.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.jrmp.Context.lookup(Context.java:185)
     [wldeploy]     ... 55 more
     [wldeploy] Caused by: java.io.EOFException
     [wldeploy]     at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(Unknown Source)
     [wldeploy]     ... 61 more

    BUILD FAILED
    C:\GB_MBR\build.xml:14: The following error occurred while executing this line:
    C:\eclipse\ant-common\buildcommon.xml:242: weblogic.Deployer$DeployerException: weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.DeployerException: Unable to connect to 't3://localhost:7001': null. Ensure the url represents a running admin server and that the credentials are correct. If using http protocol, tunneling must be enabled on the admin server.

    Total time: 12 seconds
```

Comment: I'm just moving my working code and configuration from one machine to another. The application can deploy in my old machine but not my new one.

I have compared the configuration of Weblogic between two machines. I do not know what else is missing.

Comment: Verify your server is running and verify you can deploy via the weblogic console instead of on the command line.

Comment: Thanks. There was a user group I forgot to set up.